# Javascript: if hasClass then addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to Javascript. I want to add a 'animated fadeInLeft' class to a image when the div wrap around it has a class 'active' and remove the 'animated fadeInLeft' class when the div lost it's 'active' class. Somehow it doesn't work properly.

Here is the javascript code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if ( $('#section1').hasClass('active') ) {
      $('#blueleft').addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
    }
    else {
      $('#blueleft').removeClass("animated fadeInLeft");
    }
  });
</script>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="section" id="section1">
    <h2>Wireless Digital Music System</h2>
    <p>Streaming tracks</p>
    <img id="blueleft" class="blueleft" src="img/blueleft.png" alt="blueleft">
    <img id="blueright" class="blueright" src="img/blueright.png" alt="blueright">
</div>
```

I have another Javascript script running, which will add the 'active' class to a div section. There is no problem with that. If I choose to put 'div.section' instead of '#section1', the whole script will run, and it will add class to '#blueleft'. I can see it from the inspector, also it will show a animation because I am using animated.css. But it won't work if I put '#section1'. It won't add the 'animated fadeInLeft' class. I need to use id instead of class because I have other divs that also have 'section' class name, but they have different ids. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: can you paste the code from another javascript adding class active to div section

Comment: `#section1` does not have an `active` class, so it runs `removeClass` to remove classes what are also not present. What are you expecting to happen? Sounds like you might have duplicate ID's, which is invalid and only the first one gets selected.

Comment: `div class="section active" id="section1">`

Comment: "it won't work" — What does this mean? How are you determining if it works? Are you using a DOM inspector to look at the classes an element is assigned to? (It sounds like you are testing by seeing if CSS changes are being applied, which probably means you are running into a specificity issue which can't be debugged without seeing the CSS).

Comment: Yeah, your script will be run once when the document is loaded. If you add the '.active' class programmatically, you must also execute the if statement afterwards.

Comment: @Maurice Perry So how should do it? I kind feel like that is the problem, but I don't know how to execute the if statement after the other script added the '.active' class.

Comment: @lucky13820 it seems to me that the way to go is to use CSS transitions in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you are having multiple div with same ID, this is invalid HTML and the problem is when you access an element with **$('#elementId')** it will return only first element found in HTML so you need to use for each loop as below,

```
$('div[id^="section1"]').each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('active') ) {
      $(this).find('#blueleft').addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
    }else {
      $(this).find('#blueleft').removeClass("animated fadeInLeft");
    }
})
```

this will find all the element with **section1** id and will apply the logic.

Comment: "As you are having multiple div with same ID" — What makes you think that? The question doesn't show duplicate ids in the code, and the use of a number in the id implies that the ids are unique.

Comment: @Quentin In question he mentioned that he is having some **other divs that are also named 'section'** so I thought he need to use for each loop if having same id to multiple divs. Thanks.

Comment: The code shows that "section" is a **class** name not the **id**

Answer (score -2):

```
if( $("div#section1.active").length ){
    $('#blueleft').addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
} else {
}
```

Comment: Why should the changes you have made in this game of spot-the-difference help?